# How do you plot functions for straight lines $y=mx+c$ with labels and intercepts?

Tags: plot

I've taken screen captures from other problems, but the results are poor.

I'd like to be able to do lines, and move onto quadratic etc. later.

y=3x+2

show & label

- x & y axes
- origin
- y intercept
- line, labeled for function

Comment: pgfplots is probably the most general solution, but any of the TeX-friendly drawing tools can be used.  Or you can use an external tool like gnuplot or the Mac OSX grapher to produce a PDF of your plot which you can include in TeX.  Can you be a bit more specific in your question?  As it is your question might get down voted and closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me suggest a possible solution using the `pgfplots` package.  The third chapter of the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf) is dedicated to easy-to-understand beginner tutorials.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[domain=0:3,no marks,xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y(x)$]
    \addplot+[name path=A] {2*x-1};
    \addlegendentry{$2 x - 1$};
    \addplot+[name path=B] {0.5*x+1};
    \addlegendentry{$x/2 + 1$};
    \path[name intersections={of=A and B}]
      node[draw,fill,circle,inner sep=1pt,pin={above left:Intersection}]
        at (intersection-1) {};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]